# Pi-hole fails to connect to Unbound DNS

Tags: docker, unbound

**The issue I am facing:**
Pi-hole cannot connect to Unbound DNS

**What I want to happen**

I want to use Pi-hole to filter my network, and Encrypted Unbound as DNS for privacy. I have already set-up both Pi-hole and Unbound, and both seems to be working properly on their own. Pi-hole works when I'm connected to Quad9, and Unbound can dig websites (so I'm assuming that it works. The problem is, when I start to combine the two, it stops working. I cannot connect to any websites when I'm using Unbound as the only DNS in Pi-hole.

**Details about my system:**

`````
╰─>$ neofetch
                   -`                    mika@Luna 
                  .o+`                   --------- 
                 `ooo/                   OS: Arch Linux x86_64 
                `+oooo:                  Host: VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X515EA_X515EA 1.0 
               `+oooooo:                 Kernel: 5.18.3-arch1-1 
               -+oooooo+:                Uptime: 6 hours, 50 mins 
             `/:-:++oooo+:               Packages: 983 (pacman), 10 (flatpak) 
            `/++++/+++++++:              Shell: fish 3.4.1 
           `/++++++++++++++:             Resolution: 1920x1080 
          `/+++ooooooooooooo/`           WM: i3 
         ./ooosssso++osssssso+`          Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
        .oossssso-````/ossssss+`         Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
       -osssssso.      :ssssssso.        Terminal: xfce4-terminal 
      :osssssss/        osssso+++.       Terminal Font: Monospace 12 
     /ossssssss/        +ssssooo/-       CPU: 11th Gen Intel i3-1115G4 (4) @ 3.000GHz 
   `/ossssso+/:-        -:/+osssso+-     GPU: Intel Device 9a78 
  `+sso+:-`                 `.-/+oso:    Memory: 8440MiB / 11667MiB 
 `++:.                           `-/+/
 .`                                 `/
`````

Pi-hole was installted via Docker

```
╰─>$ sudo docker ps
[sudo] password for mika: 
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND      CREATED       STATUS                 PORTS                                                                                                             NAMES
fd54d6c0a3fa   pihole/pihole:latest   "/s6-init"   4 hours ago   Up 4 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:53->53/tcp, :::53->53/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:53->53/udp, :::80->80/tcp, :::53->53/udp, 67/udp   pihole
```

```
╰─>$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: "3"

# More info at https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole/ and https://docs.pi-hole.net/
services:
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    # For DHCP it is recommended to remove these ports and instead add: network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "53:53/tcp"
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "80:80/tcp"
    environment:
      TZ: 'America/Chicago'
      # WEBPASSWORD: 'set a secure password here or it will be random'
    # Volumes store your data between container upgrades
    volumes:
      - './etc-pihole:/etc/pihole'
      - './etc-dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d'    
    #   https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole#note-on-capabilities
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN # Required if you are using Pi-hole as your DHCP server, else not needed
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Unbound was installed via pacman
`unbound.conf`

```
server:
    # If no logfile is specified, syslog is used
    logfile: /var/log/unbound/unbound.log
    verbosity: 0

    interface: 127.0.0.1
    port: 5335
    do-ip4: yes
    do-udp: yes
    do-tcp: yes

    # May be set to yes if you have IPv6 connectivity
    do-ip6: no

    # You want to leave this to no unless you have *native* IPv6. With 6to4 and
    # Terredo tunnels your web browser should favor IPv4 for the same reasons
    prefer-ip6: no

    # Use this only when you downloaded the list of primary root servers!
    # If you use the default dns-root-data package, unbound will find it automatically
    #root-hints: /var/lib/unbound/root.hints

    # Trust glue only if it is within the server's authority
    harden-glue: yes

    # Require DNSSEC data for trust-anchored zones, if such data is absent, the zone becomes BOGUS
    harden-dnssec-stripped: yes

    # Don't use Capitalization randomization as it known to cause DNSSEC issues sometimes
    # see https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/unbound-stubby-or-dnscrypt-proxy/9378 for further details
    use-caps-for-id: no

    # Reduce EDNS reassembly buffer size.
    # IP fragmentation is unreliable on the Internet today, and can cause
    # transmission failures when large DNS messages are sent via UDP. Even
    # when fragmentation does work, it may not be secure; it is theoretically
    # possible to spoof parts of a fragmented DNS message, without easy
    # detection at the receiving end. Recently, there was an excellent study
    # >>> Defragmenting DNS - Determining the optimal maximum UDP response size for DNS <<<
    # by Axel Koolhaas, and Tjeerd Slokker (https://indico.dns-oarc.net/event/36/contributions/776/)
    # in collaboration with NLnet Labs explored DNS using real world data from the
    # the RIPE Atlas probes and the researchers suggested different values for
    # IPv4 and IPv6 and in different scenarios. They advise that servers should
    # be configured to limit DNS messages sent over UDP to a size that will not
    # trigger fragmentation on typical network links. DNS servers can switch
    # from UDP to TCP when a DNS response is too big to fit in this limited
    # buffer size. This value has also been suggested in DNS Flag Day 2020.
    edns-buffer-size: 1232

    # Perform prefetching of close to expired message cache entries
    # This only applies to domains that have been frequently queried
    prefetch: yes

    # One thread should be sufficient, can be increased on beefy machines. In reality for most users running on small networks or on a single machine, it should be unnecessary to seek performance enhancement by increasing num-threads above 1.
    num-threads: 1

    # Ensure kernel buffer is large enough to not lose messages in traffic spikes
    so-rcvbuf: 1m

    # Ensure privacy of local IP ranges
    private-address: 192.168.0.0/16
    private-address: 169.254.0.0/16
    private-address: 172.16.0.0/12
    private-address: 10.0.0.0/8
    private-address: fd00::/8
    private-address: fe80::/10

    do-not-query-localhost: no
    tls-system-cert: yes

# control which clients are allowed to make (recursive) queries
access-control: 127.0.0.1/32 allow_snoop
access-control: ::1 allow_snoop
access-control: 127.0.0.0/8 allow
access-control: 192.168.1.0/24 allow

# Upstream Servers
forward-zone:
  name: "."
  forward-tls-upstream: yes
  forward-addr: 45.90.28.0#[redacted].dns1.nextdns.io
  forward-addr: 2a07:a8c0::#[redacted].dns1.nextdns.io
  forward-addr: 45.90.30.0#[redacted].dns2.nextdns.io
  forward-addr: 2a07:a8c1::#[redacted].dns2.nextdns.io
```

Unbound DNS seems working when digging websites

```
╰─>$ dig sigok.verteiltesysteme.net @127.0.0.1 -p 5335

; <<>> DiG 9.18.3 <<>> sigok.verteiltesysteme.net @127.0.0.1 -p 5335
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 23492
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;sigok.verteiltesysteme.net.    IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
sigok.verteiltesysteme.net. 30  IN  A   134.91.78.139

;; Query time: 2073 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#5335(127.0.0.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Fri Jun 17 01:24:05 +08 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 71
```

```
╰─>$ dig sigfail.verteiltesysteme.net @127.0.0.1 -p 5335

; <<>> DiG 9.18.3 <<>> sigfail.verteiltesysteme.net @127.0.0.1 -p 5335
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 51854
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;sigfail.verteiltesysteme.net.  IN  A

;; Query time: 2766 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#5335(127.0.0.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Fri Jun 17 01:24:22 +08 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 57
```

Status of Unbound

```
╰─>$ systemctl status unbound
● unbound.service - Validating, recursive, and caching DNS resolver
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/unbound.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-06-16 23:08:16 +08; 2h 21min ago
       Docs: man:unbound(8)
   Main PID: 208332 (unbound)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 13976)
     Memory: 2.4M
        CPU: 64ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/unbound.service
             └─208332 /usr/bin/unbound -d -p
```

**What I have changed since installing Pi-hole:**

I changed my DNS server to `127.0.0.1#5335` to use Unbound DNS
[Pi-hole DNS Servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB8af.png)

But I fail to load any website until I enable other DNS resolvers (Quad9)

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the default network mode (bridge), containers have their network namespace isolated from that of the host, the loopback address does not have the same meaning in the context of one container as it does in the context of the host.

You should point pihole to one of the IP addresses used by the host system, such as the IP address on the physical NIC or the IP address on the bridge created for your Docker network.

For more information about Docker networking:

- https://docs.docker.com/network/
- https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/
- https://docs.docker.com/network/host/